# JMeter structure warmup

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

My project structure in JMeter is now:

[image]

But there are some limitations:

- A lot of duplicate transaction/module controllers
- The only once controller is not working with the UltimateThreadGroup
- Its not possible to use the setUp thread, because the cache is not shared between threads
- The time from the warmup is different, i cant use the offset in my Synthesis Report

What is a better structure to skip the warmup (first threadrun) from my results?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just remove 1st execution of each sampler for each thread (virtual user) you can play the following trick:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request you want to ignore (or according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) if you want to remove the first execution of other samplers)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (vars.getIteration() == 1) {
       prev.setIgnore()
   }
   ```

   where:

   - `vars` - is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class and [getIteration()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration--) function returns the current Thread Group loop number
   - `prev` - is a shorthand for the [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class and [setIgnore()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) function tells JMeter to discard the result

Comment: Up-voted! Please also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73092432/jmeter-to-ignore-warmup-period. thx!